# Node.js Mysql Insert Object with On Dublicate

Tags: mysql, node.js

How this query would be correct?

```
let newUser = {
    user_id:'123456',
    user_name:'someone'
    }

con.query('INSERT INTO users SET ? ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ?', newUser, (err,rows) => {
        if(err) throw err;
    });
```

At the moment i get a syntax error after UPDATE

**EDIT**

```
Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1


 sql: "INSERT INTO users SET `user_id` = '', `user_name` = '' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ?"
```

**TABLE STRUCTURE**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `users`;
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_Id` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
  `user_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`user_Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=86 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

Comment: share the complete error log and the query generates

Comment: Edited values are empty cause i deleted the real ones here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of question marks should be equal to the size of the array.
You have to pass 2 params

```
let newUser = {
    user_id:'123456',
    user_name:'someone'
    }

con.query('INSERT INTO users SET ? ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ?', [newUser, newUser], (err,rows) => {
        if(err) throw err;
    });
```

Comment: con.query('INSERT INTO users SET ? ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ?', user, user (err,rows) => {
                                                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Malformed arrow function parameter list

Comment: `[newUser, newUser]` is an array parameter con.query has 3 params 1. query, 2. input values, 3. callback

Comment: Okey got it so far :) but when i now change the user_name it makes a new entry. I only want having the user_id onces in my table

Comment: And it makes now everytime a new entry ... still when it has same values

Comment: check with the `primary key` and `unique key` indexes `ON DUPLICATE` which check for those keys

Comment: How i do this ?

Comment: send the structure of the table, you might be primary key on user_id `SHOW create table users`

Comment: i updated the Question Also added primary key to user_id but still it makes new entry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222473/discussion-between-user13405446-and-arvi).